# Configuring TFS Extensions for SharePoint on remote server article has some error?

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, configure

This paragraph looks like error:

> If you want to run SharePoint Products on a server other than Team
> Foundation Server, you must install Team Foundation Server on the
> SharePoint server and then configure the TFS Extensions for
> SharePoint. This installs all of TFS on the SharePoint server,
> including the TFS SharePoint Extensions. The application tier, the
> build server, and the proxy server appear in the TFS administration
> console, but you do not have to configure any of these additional
> features.
>
> <sup>[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh548140(v=vs.120).aspx)</sup>

This article is about Configuring TFS Extensions for SharePoint on remote server.

Then, why would someone install TFS server on SharePoint server again if he has already got the TFS server installed on another machine? Isn't it that he will only install the SharePoint extension on the SharePoint server?

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing TFS on the server installs the required prerequisites, TFS Client Object Model, The Server Object model, the WSP that installs the SharePoint Extensions and a few other items. These elements are required for the Sharepoint Extensions to connect to the remote TFS server.

Installing these only drops these bits, but does not activate anything. There will be no running services, no other bits. That is what the Configure step will do, which you will skip for these steps.

So, no, this is not a bug in the documentation. You need to install TFS on the server. it makes sense as it installs all the prerequisites. **again** **installing the binaries on the server doesn't configure** any of the features. It's the same as the first stage of installing SharePoint, it drops the bits, but doesn't create any services, websites or databases until you **configure**. And you will configure only the one feature you need, which is the SharePoint integration.

It is probably possible to manually install all the prerequisites, register the TFS server to the client object model and manually deploy the WSP, but that is not the standard way of doing it.

Comment: Did'nt you see any mistake in the top 3 lines of the article quoted in my question? The article starts with -> If you want to run SharePoint Products on a server other than Team Foundation Server. Then, later says -> This installs all of TFS on the SharePoint server

Comment: Ok thanks, did you see the next paragraph in the link -> As an alternative, you can use a special installer (tfs_sharePointExtensions.exe) to install just the TFS Extensions on the SharePoint server. Only the TFS Extensions for SharePoint will appear in the TFS administration console. What do you suggest should we follow the para 1 or para 2. ANy advice will be usefull. Thanks :)

Comment: I'd follow 1+2,unless you have very strong objections against it.  It's easier to upgrade, easier to administer and the standard way most people do this.

Comment: On which server should I configure the TFS extensions for Sharepoint? Is it on the SharePoint server or the TFS server?

Comment: But if I do that, then on the TFS server admin console, under the Team project collections -> I cannot see any option for SharePoint site tab (next to the Reports Folder tab)